# What are the Weller "Steckverbinder für Ablage" used for?

Tags: soldering

I just bought a Weller WXMP Soldering Iron and got these two plastic things (pictures) in the package.
I have searched the web but can't find any instructions on what to use them for.
What are they used for?

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are used to connect more than one soldering iron holder to each other. You can see them in this picture:

[image]

Typically this is used when you have a station with multiple soldering irons (set for different temperatures or different tips).

[image]

You use the plastic connectors to join the holders together and add a little space between them.

Answer (score 1):

"Steckverbinder für Ablage" means "connector for storage" auf Deutsch.  Without more context -- I dunno.  What might those connect to?  Would whatever they connect to need protection from dust or banging around?

From the comment:

> Ablage does not mean "Storage" but "Tool rest" here. And that is exactly what it seems to be intended to verbinden (connect) by stecken (plugging).

This is what I get for thinking I can function in German.

Comment: Ablage does not mean "Storage" but "Tool rest" here. And that is exactly what it seems to be intended to verbinden (connect) by stecken (plugging).

Comment: Danke!  Miner deutchen Vortshatz ist kleine.